# What does it mean when a virtual machine can only run on x86 hardware?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, virtual-host

I am learning about different kinds of virtualization.

As I learn about this concept I am often times presented with documentation that says the virtualization software "requires x86 processors". I am confused by this because does this mean that virtualization technology can only run on a 32 bit OS (which would make no sense)?

I am thinking more of a server application in which multiple virtual servers (guests) are run on one host. If the host computer has to have a 32-bit processor and 32-bit OS, I can hardly see how that would work being that it needs to share the maximum of 4GB of RAM with the virtual guests- there would simply not be enough resources to run multiple guests? I have done some digging and I cannot seem to find much on this subject.

Comment: Check out [x86 virtualization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization) on Wikipedia.

Comment: All processors are x86 unless they are not ( i.e. PowerPC, AMD, ect. ).  I would have to assume the documentation you are looking at is limited to x86 hypervisors.  Please clarify your question.

Comment: @Ramhound I think you meant ARM, not AMD.

Comment: Yes; indeed I meant ARM not AMD

Answer (score 1):

The is hopefully no 32 bit restriction. x86 is to be taken as a generic term encompassing both x86 and x86-64 (a.k.a. amd64) architectures and opposed to architectures like SPARC, ARM, PA-RISC, Alpha, Power, Itanium and the likes.

Answer (score 0):

When it says "x86 processors" it means processors that are capable of operating on the x86 Instruction Set Architecture usually Intel/AMD. So the virtualization technology you are trying to install can only run on this hardware.

So, now you must either download the x86-compatible installer of the same virtualization technology you want to use or change to a x86 compatible virtualization technology or buy a CPU that support your current virtualization software. Almost every virtualization software out there has a x86 version.